# How can I include some js file in JSFL file?

Tags: actionscript, jsfl

I'm using JSFL to writing some script, I need parse json string from some config files, so I need the JSFL can parse json string, but JSFL seems can't do this. then I thinks to include some json lib, like json.js, to JSFL file.

Way can I include the json.js file to my JSFL file?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute bare minimum would be:

```
// #include Config._jsfl
var scriptPath = FLfile.uriToPlatformPath(fl.scriptURI);
var scriptPathEnd = scriptPath.lastIndexOf("\\");
scriptPath = scriptPath.slice(0, scriptPathEnd + 1);
fl.runScript(FLfile.platformPathToURI(scriptPath + "Config._jsfl"));            /*jsl:import Config._jsfl*/
```

This is more or less copied from my code, JSL tags included.  I make the extensions on any libraries to be ._jsfl so that if it's in Flash's Commands folder, they don't show up in the menu.

I wrote a set of static classes (a Logging system, URI conversions, array utility functions) and wrote a global `include` function using them to automatically convert a relative path to an absolute URI based upon the running scripts location so that I could just say `include("file._jsfl");` to simplify my scripts. HOWEVER all my scripts have to do that first include as shown above to gain the `include` function.  Since my include function relies on a handful of static classes, I've not pasted it here.

Edit: spelling error.

Answer (score 1):

If the library is local, you can store it in a subfolder of your Flash config path, i.e.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\language\Configuration\jslibs
```

Then, it is quite easy to include it in a single line:

```
fl.runScript(fl.configURI + "jslibs/file.js");
```